# One Table Data as Column Headings in Another table Columns

Tags: mysql, database

Two Table 
1.ClassSubjectTable and 2.SubjectTable

**ClassSubjectTable**

```
------------------------------------
class_subject_id |subject1 |subject2
------------------------------------
  1 (General Id) |   1      |    2  -----> are subject_id's
```

**SubjectTable**

```
-------------------------
subject_id | subject_name
-------------------------
      1    |  Maths
      2    |  Science
```

I want to get

```
------------------------------------
class_subject_id |subject1 |subject2
------------------------------------
       1         |Maths    | Science
```

More over there is no relation between them. Is it Possible? How?

Comment: You should read about using primary and foreign keys. Generally SO is not a site where other people will do the work for you. Please ask a specific question, then you will get a specific answer to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.class_subject_id, s1.subject_name AS subject1, s2.subject_name AS subject2
FROM ClassSubjectTable c
LEFT JOIN SubjectTable s1
  ON c.subject1 = s1.subject_id
LEFT JOIN SubjectTable s2
  ON c.subject2 = s2.subject_id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a9e0/3/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, But   class_subject_id   is  a auto increment field not related with subject_id in SubjetTable